# Magento 2 : Security Check Can Not be Verified!

Tags: magento2, security-scan-tool

I use magento 2.2.2. I try to have a security check provided by Magento at
https://account.magento.com/scanner/index/form/
I add confirmation code, I check it in source of my site, but when I try to verify my site, I do not get it verified!
Anyboady can help me why?
I made a film too. please, look at this film
http://recordit.co/r1mii3v58B
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the "**Scripts and Style Sheets**" in the "**HTML Head**" section and not "Footer"

Answer (score 0):

If above doesn't work, see https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Security-Scan-Tool/td-p/92549.  This places the meta tag in default_head_blocks.xml. This worked for me.  Putting the html tag in the default_head_blocks.xml file did not work for me.